# EasyMock 3.0 Mocked class needs to throw an exception if any method gets called

Tags: java, exception, easymock

I'd like to mock a class so it throws an exception if any method is called. The reason why i want to do this, is that i don't want a NullpointerException in my tests, I'd rather mock every object, declared as an instance variable which is null with the exception-stuff, so if a method on it gets called I get a proper exception, and I see imediatly whats wrong. Does EasyMock 3.0 provide such a thing, or do I need to do it some other way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that EasyMock's default behavior? Any unexpected calls on a mocked object lead to an Exception once you call `EasyMock.verify(mocks)`. Please see the EasyMock documentation - the "Nice Mocks" section explains this: http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html

The following test fails for me with an `AssertionError`, this should be what you're looking for:

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {
    List list = EasyMock.createMock(List.class);

    EasyMock.replay(list);

    list.size();

    EasyMock.verify(list);
}
```

Comment: In my example list would be null, because someone forgot to declare or removed it accidentally (e.g. in @Before)!
And I'm then setting this object in another class, which uses it, so i will have a Nullpointer there. I'd like to prevent that and throw a nicer exception if it happens. You are then much faster to figure out what the problem is. Checking that before running tests isn't what I want, because not every test uses every object created in before! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can expect an exception when its called, considering the same list example

```
List list = EasyMock.createMock(List.class);
EasyMock.expect(list.size()).andThrow(new OurOwnException()).anyTimes();
EasyMock.replay(list);
```

This will always throw your custom exception whenever size() method is called.
Do you expect this behavior?

Comment: This is fine, but is there a way to do this for **every method** on `list`? In the example only the `size` method is configured, and is not practical to do it for every method individually.